# File chooser dialog not closing

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Here is my code for file chooser dialog operation...

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
fc.setTitle("Pointel File");
File file1 = fc.showOpenDialog(MainFrame.objComponent.getPrimaryStage());

int i =0;
while(i < 90000){
System.out.println(i);
i++;
}
```

In the above code, the dialog is waiting until the 'while' loop completes execution rather than closing itself the moment we click 'open' button.

Am I missing something in the code which will close the dialog the moment we click the 'Open' or 'Cancel' button?
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: +1  So funny to encounter these kind of situations .. :) Just kidding. I guess, they are running in the same thread that is why this issue.

Comment: @Che Thank you for the quick reply. I tried it in another thread but the problem was, one of my other UI components won't update properly, when called from the other thread. So I am forced to put this in the same thread. Any other work around while doing in the same thread.

Comment: @David Kroukamp Can you please specify which class and package does the Thread, you are talking about, exists? Or if this  `javafx.concurrent.Task` is what you are talking about; if so can you please let me know which jar file does this belong to?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a long running on your UI's [Application Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html) which should not be done, or else UI will become unresponsive.

Rather create a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or `Thread` to do long running processes on *application thread*.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) link for more on Concurrency in JavaFX

Here is a short example of `Task`:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

....

FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
fc.setTitle("Pointel File");
File file1 = fc.showOpenDialog(MainFrame.objComponent.getPrimaryStage());

    final Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 90000) {
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
```

Also remember if you modify any JavaFX UI components wrap the code in [`Platform.runLater(Runnable r)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) block like this:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

....

final Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 90000) {
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
        }
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {//updates ui on application thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //put any updates to ui here dont run the long running code in this block or the same will happen as doing a long running task on app thread
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
};
Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried this but the compiler says that there is no such method. The thread method doesn't accept 'task' parameter.

Comment: @Freakyuser are you sure you have the correct import for Thread? it should not be java rather javafx

Comment: @Freakyuser try the above code, sorry my other code had alot of typos. I tested the above code and all seems fine

Comment: Should I use a javafx jar file or install javafx? I am currently using javafx-2.jar. Please bare with me, I am a beginner to this.

Answer (score 0):

Never do the GUI and the computational tasks on the same thread. Your UI should be running on one thread and your computational tasks should be on other threads. UI becomes unresponsive if they both are running on the same thread.

Firstly read about,

[Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

[The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

[SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Using the `Event Dispatch Thread`, you can dispatch your UI threads. Look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636591/where-is-the-event-dispatch-thread-called) given by @Erick Robertson related to `EDT`.

Many posts available in SO about the above stated topics.